# issue when populating spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have populated a spinner with some data, like this:

```
adapter =
newSpinAdapter(this,com.Orange.R.layout.spinnerrowlist,spinnerInfo);                  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(com.Orange.R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);
previousVisitCommentsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

public class UserComments {
    public String coach;
    public String comment;
    public String date;

    public UserComments(String coach, String comment, String date) {
        this.coach = coach;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.date = date;
    }
}

    public class SpinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserComments>{
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<UserComments> spinnerInfo;

        public SpinAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<UserComments> spinnerInfo){
            super(context, textViewResourceId, spinnerInfo);
            this.spinnerInfo = spinnerInfo;
        }

        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.spinnerrowlist, null);
    }

            Visit.UserComments info = spinnerInfo.get(position);

            if (info != null) {
        TextView spinneritem1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_spinner1);
        TextView spinneritem2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_spinner2);
                    TextView spinneritem3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_spinner3);

        if (spinneritem1 != null) {
                        spinneritem1.setText(info.coach);
                        spinneritem1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.medium_gray));
        }

        if (spinneritem2 != null) {
                        spinneritem2.setText(info.comment);
                        spinneritem2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.medium_gray));
            }

                    if (spinneritem3 != null) {
                        spinneritem3.setText(info.date);
                        spinneritem3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.medium_gray));
            }

        }
            return v;
        }

    }
```

That is a part of my code. This is how the spinner looks:
[image: here is my picture]

This is ok.

But when I click on it I looks like this:
[image: here is my image]

It doesn't show the same data as in the state when it is not selected!!!!
Data that should be displayed when selected should be : `2012-09-03 second 11`. Anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong??? and what is the solution. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override `toString` in your `UserComments` class, for example:

```
public class UserComments {
    public String coach;
    public String comment;
    public String date;

    public UserComments(String coach, String comment, String date) {
        this.coach = coach;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return date + " " + comment + " " + coach;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't override `toString`, your spinner uses the default `toString` method, inherited from `Object`, which prints the class of the object followed by its internal hashcode.

Answer (score 3):

In `UserComments` override `toString` method and return text you want to be visible in your spinner.